# How to working with xml nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xslt-1.0, dtd, httpwebresponse

I have program with response from website in the xml format with namespace.

**example program:**

```
        string responsedata;//response data from website


        //Creat new XMLdoc object for response data
        XmlDocument ResponseDataXml = new XmlDocument();
        ResponseDataXml.InnerXml= responsedata;
        XmlNamespaceManager xnsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(ResponseDataXml.NameTable);
        xnsm.AddNamespace("ps","http://example.com/namespace/ps");


        //create xml document fro validating DTD
        XmlDocument ValidateXml = new XmlDocument();

        //select Nodes <ps:results> ... <result>
        XmlNodeList NodesResults = ResponseDataXml.SelectNodes("ps:results/result");

        foreach (XmlNode node in NodesResults)
        {
            ValidateXml.InnerText= "";
            ValidateXml.InnerText += "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
            ValidateXml.InnerText += "<!DOCTYPE SouborN1A SYSTEM \"validate_dtd.dtd\">";
            ValidateXml.InnerText+=node.InnerXml;
            ValidateXml.Save("validate_temp.xml");

            if (validate("validate_temp.xml"))//validate() return true if document is valid
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Result:" + node.Attributes["id"] + " is valid !!!!!");
                // here i can append "result" node in new xml document "Valid_result.xml"
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Result:"+ node.Attributes["id"] + "i invalid !!!!!");
                // here i can append "result" in new xml document invalid result in to "invalid_result.xml"
            }
        }
```

**Input postdata:**

```
<ps:report xmlns:ps="example.com.....">
    <results xmlns:ps="example.com....." ps:Identifikation="999999">
        <result id="11125"> 
         .......
        </result>
        <result id="1100"> 
         .......
        </result>
        <result id="111999055"> 
         .......
        </result>
        <result id="100000"> 
         .......
        </result>
    </results>
</ps:report>
```

Please help me... :)

I do not know how to proceed, and work with a given output, 
I need mainly validate the item separately and then store in a xml file.

I apologize for my English.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this question is fairly broad, but generally speaking everything can be done with XML libraries in C#. For example, use the [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to create elements and then simply append those elements to the existing nodes.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var output = new XmlDocument();
        output.AppendChild(output.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));

        var xmlns = new XmlNamespaceManager(output.NameTable);

        var root = output.CreateElement("ps", "report", "http://example.com/namespace/ps");

        var list = output.CreateElement("ps", "results", "http://example.com/namespace/ps");
        list.Attributes.Append(output.CreateAttribute("Identifikation"));
        list.Attributes[0].Value = "999999";
        root.AppendChild(list);

        var item = output.CreateElement("ps", "result", "http://example.com/namespace/ps");
        item.Attributes.Append(output.CreateAttribute("id"));
        item.Attributes[0].Value = "11125";
        list.AppendChild(item);

        //TODO: Append more validation messages.

        output.AppendChild(root);

        output.WriteTo(new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out));
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Produces a document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ps:report xmlns:ps="http://example.com/namespace/ps">
    <ps:results Identifikation="999999">
        <ps:result id="11125" />
    </ps:results>
</ps:report>
```